# extjs 4 ajax request json error decode while querying for plain text

Tags: ajax, json, extjs, text, decode

These code:

```
        Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'modules/tags.cfc?method=getHtml',
        success: function(response, opts) {
            //var obj = response.responseText;
            console.dir(response, opts);
            //this.html=obj;
        },
        failure: function(response, opts) {
           // console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
        }
    },this);
```

Is throwing this error:

> [E] Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:

```
    ihooolog @ ext-all-dev.js:12297Ext.Error.Ext.extend.statics.raise @ ext-all-dev.js:11394Ext.JSON.me.decode @ ext-all-dev.js:11800MIS.Methods.AjaxTrigger @ MIS.Methods.js?{ts '2015-08-06 19:33:54'}:45fire @ ext-all-dev.js:16019continueFireEvent @ ext-all-dev.js:17883fireEventArgs @ ext-all-dev.js:17854fireEvent @ ext-all-dev.js:17831Ext.define.onComplete @ ext-all-dev.js:48201Ext.define.onStateChange @ ext-all-dev.js:48148(anonymous function) @ ext-all-dev.js:3332
```

When I return a simple string "ihooo" from the server. I can't figure out why he is trying to decode JSON, I don't see where...

The response headers are:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Thu, 06 Aug 2015 17:37:35 GMT

And the response itself if realy just a simple text.

The component & function (**tags.cfc**):

```
<cfcomponent extends="base" output="false">
<cffunction name="getHtml" access="remote" returnformat="plain" returntype="String">
    <cfreturn "ihooo">
</cffunction>
```

Any help/clue would be gratly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it caused by [console.dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir), which is trying to output the property of a javascript object?

Try:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'modules/tags.cfc?method=getHtml',
    success: function(response, opts) {
        var obj = response.responseText;
        console.dir(obj);
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
       // console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
},this);
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I return a simple string "ihooo" from the server. I can't figure
>   out why he is trying to decode JSON, I don't see where

Read the error message. It is telling that there is a call to `Ext.JSON.decode` in your `MIS.Methods.js` file at line 45.

Just don't do it on simple strings "ihooo" :)